# Epplus ASP.NET Display workbook in iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net, epplus

I have just begun using Epplus and have successfully created a workbook with several spreadsheets.  I need to be able to display this file in an webpage.  When using interop, this was incredibly easy.  How can I do the same in Epplus?

Comment: Do you mean, that xlsx-file need to be downloadable in website?

Comment: No.  I wish to display the workbook in the web page.

Comment: Websites do not work that way. Only the client PC can show the file after it has been downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest you following approaches for what you are trying to achieve.

> **Option 1:**
>
> If you ready to pay you can go for Office 365 which gives you feature
>   to embed a excel file in iFrame.
>
> **Option 2:**
>
> **Convert to PDF**. If your excel is read only better covert it to PDF and use [PDF.JS](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) with [Viewer.js](http://viewerjs.org/) to embed inside a page.
>    This will be the best solution as there is no dependency on any
>    additional plugin at the client side. It works just with plain HTML
>    and JavaScript.
>
> **Option 3**-
>   Google docs, if your data is not sensitive, you can use google docs to upload the excel and embed inside your page.
>
> **Option 4** :
>
> Go for excel like grids, this will support your view part also it can
>   support updating data back to the database if required. For this you
>   can use [Handsontable](https://jspreadsheets.com/handsontable.html)